# Counting occurrence of item in csv file

Tags: python, csv, file

I need to produce the number of occurrences of a word in a csv file. The output needs to list each word and the number of times it appears in the file. So if the file looks like:

house, red, knife, red, car, house, Red

the output would be:

house 2

red 2

knife 1

car 1

Red 1

I've tried creating a dictionary and incrementing the words and a count as the key and value as some other posts have suggested but got an error. I've seen similar problems on here use the Counter method but I'm not allowed to use that. Here's what I have so far. The `print(word_count_dict)` statement was just to see if the concept would work:

```
import csv

with open('afile.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    words = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    word_count_dict = {}
    for i in words:
        if i not in word_count_dict:
            word_count_dict[i] = 0
        word_count_dict[i] += 1
        
    print(word_count_dict)
```

Comment: What's the problem or question?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please do not use `dict` as a variable name as it's included as Python data-type. Try `word_count_dict`.

Comment: Is this failing? Are there any errors?

Comment: Take a look at the Counter class in the *collections* module

Comment: @Cobra Agree for best practices, but they specifically mentioned that they cannot use the `Counter` class. Perhaps it's a HW problem

Comment: @StonedTensor I really need to learn to read the entire question. My bad

Comment: @StonedTensor I've edited it as you suggested. The error I get is "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"

Answer (score 0):

```
cat count.csv                                                                                                                                                              
house,red,knife,red,car,house,Red

import csv

with open('count.csv') as csv_file:
    ct_dict = {}
    c_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in c_reader:
        for val in row:
            if ct_dict.get(val):
                ct_dict[val] += 1
            else:
                ct_dict.update({val: 1})
ct_dict                                                                                                                                                                    
{'house': 2, 'red': 2, 'knife': 1, 'car': 1, 'Red': 1}
```